# Mongoose won't validate user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my [user model](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef5e79cfb69e14615c8c) and this is my [js file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e8f73b76a3b98786074b) that searches for email in database.

When passing the correct email to following code, it doesn't find the user in database although the email is correct. Should I do it somehow different?

```
  workflow.on('patchUser', function(token, hash) {
var conditions = { email: req.body.email.toLowerCase() };
var fieldsToSet = {
  resetPasswordToken: hash,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date.now() + 10000000
};
req.app.db.models.User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, fieldsToSet, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return workflow.emit('exception', err);
  }

  if (!user) {
    workflow.outcome.errors.push("Can't find any email match it");
    return workflow.emit('response');
  }

  workflow.emit('sendEmail', token, user);
});
```

});

`user` is always null even thought the correct email is passed.

Comment: The code looks fine, so can you edit your question to show the value of `req.body.email` and the doc you're expecting to update?

Comment: Try this and see if you get anything: req.app.db.models.User.find(conditions).exec(function(err, results){
  res.json(results);
  //console.log(results[0]);
 });